# Creating an instance of a CalendarView

Tags: android, constructor, android-calendar

In my onCreate method i have the following line of code.

```
CalendarView calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.cal);
```

I'm trying to get the current selected date from this CalendarView and convert it to a String but in the method im using to do this calendar.getDate(); is causing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access your CalendarView object in all of your class scope (e.g method,subclasses etc.) and use it's properties,methods etc. just create your reference before your onCreate method.

```
CalendarView calendar;
```

And then initiliaze it in your onCreate method by accessing your layout.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); //mylayout refers to your layout that you want to display 
calendar = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarid); //Refers to CalendarView that you declared in your layout.

}
```

And about context just like it's name it keeps the info about either your activies or the application itself.For more info check this.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, once you defined it in the XML, it will be instantiated by Dalvik, you don't need to do that, what you do need to do, is get the reference to the instance. This is done like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main); // assuming your layout XML is called main
    CalenderView calendar = (CalenderView) findViewById(R.id.theCalendarId); // the ID you gave in the XML
    // Now you can refer to the calendar.
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this has confused me more, so i've created an object called calendar out of my CalendarView how would i get the current selected date from this? I can't call the methods listed in the documentation.

Comment: 1. You should not create a new object, as it will not be the same object that is displayed on the screen. 2. why can't you use the methods in the documentation?

Comment: In the methods listed for CalendarView there is one called getDate() which im guessing i would call and convert to string but when i do calendar. that method isnt one of the ones listed.